# ReportViewer format text with HTML Tags

Tags: html, formatting, controls, format, reportviewer

Is there a way to simply format text within the ReportViewer Control so it is formatted correctly and the tags do not display.

I have text within a database field stored similar to the following: 
*`this is some text.<p/><p>more textaslkdflsdlfkdslskfasldf<p/><p>&nbsp;</p><p>asdkfksadjf &ndash; aslkfdskfd</p>`*

I'd like it to display normally (ideally) with the appropriate formatting

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: probably not the most elegant solution, but I ended up doing a search and replace for the necessary tags within the text. In my case the # and types of  tags were minimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can creating Placeholder Text in a Text Box,and set markup type to "HTML - Interpret HTML tag as styles".
[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645967.aspx) is MSDN help.